# DOCX tries to open in Office Web Apps even with feature turned off

Tags: office-web-apps

I recently exported a subweb and imported into a new site collection.  All of the Word docs on the new site try to open in Office Web Apps, but fail with error: Word Web App cannot open this document for viewing because of an unexpected error.  To view this document, open it in Microsoft Word.  Edit in OWA works fine.  It even tries to open the docs in OWA even if I turn that site collection feature off.

ULS logs show:
RequestDispatcher: response received for document F56850....
Conversion response received: CantFindSourceDocument
DocumentInfoCache.RemoveDocumentInfo: docId=d=F56850....

Just found out the previous site collection had the document ID feature turned on and the new site collection does not.  Any ideas how to fix this and get rid of the document IDs?
I even tried deleting all the docs and copying them back over, but same results.

Thanks for any response,
hockera